# Select max 1 record per year from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to extract data from a MySQL table, but am not allowed to include a record if there's a previous record less than a year old.

Given the following records, only the records **1**, **3** and **5** should be included (because record 2 was created 1 month after record 1, and record 4 was created 1 month after record 3):

```
1   2019-12-21
2   2020-01-21
3   2021-12-21
4   2022-01-21
5   2023-12-21
```

I came up with the following non-functional solution:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    table t 
WHERE 
    (created_at > DATE_ADD(
        (SELECT 
            created_at 
        FROM 
            table t2 
        WHERE 
            t2.created_at < t.created_at 
        ORDER BY 
            t2.created_at 
        DESC LIMIT 1), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

But this only returns the first and the last record, but not the third:

```
1   2019-12-21
5   2023-12-21
```

I know why: the third record gets excluded because record 2 is less than a year old. But record 2 shouldn't be taken into account, because it won't make the list itself.

How can I solve this?

Comment: max record per year <> record if more than a year from prev. record

Comment: `created_at - LAG(created_at)` in CTE.

Comment: Aside, relational databases have *rows*, not records.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lag`, assuming your MySql supports it, you can calculate the difference in months using `period_diff`

```
with d as (
  select * , 
    period_diff(extract(year_month FROM date),
      extract(year_month from lag(date,1,date) over (order by date))
    ) as m
  from t
 )
 select id, date
 from d
 where m=0 or m>12
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d210e156ef490609165f9a88e22be50)